# Rename filenames in different folders

Tags: shell-script, rename

I have a bunch of directories like the following with multiple files in each of them

```
.
 ├── 20150320
 ├── 20150321
 ├── 20150322
 ├── 20150323
 ├── 20150324
 ├── 20150325
 ...
```

Then I've put together a little script to loop over every file in every directory and convert the file to another format, like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

path="/home/juve/Projectes/leon_CC"

echo "SAC conversion"

for folder in $path/*/; do
  cd $folder
  Files=*BHZ
  for f in *BHZ; do
     /opt/mseed2sac-2.3/mseed2sac -v -C HHZ $f
     rm -r $f
  done
done
```

The conversion outputs a filename that I want to modify, in the form of
`CA.UTG2..HHZ.D.2015.080.225956.SAC`. What I need is to rename it to `2015.080.225956.UTG2.HHZ.SAC` where `SAC` is the file extension.

I'm using `rename-perl` for this. For now I've used the following with different success:

`rename -n 's/.{3}(.*)/$1/'` produces `UTG2..BHZ.D.2015.080.225956.SAC` which is part of what I need.

If tried also `rename -n 's/(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)(\.SAC)/$4$5$6$1$2'` which produces an error `Substitution replacement not terminated at line 1, in:`

Any hint would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I found the answer:

`rename -n 's/(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)(\.SAC)/$5.$6.$7.$2$3$8/'`

Thanks for all the input

Comment: Note that your script deletes _all_ `*BHZ` files after processing the first one. Is that really intended? Did you mean to have the `rm` after the loop and not inside it? Or maybe you wanted `rm "$f"` and not `rm -r *BHZ`?

Comment: Hello, that is intended. The flag `-C` allows to manipulate that part of the string using `mseed2sac`. Correct, the `rm` should be outside of the loop as there are many files that would get destroyed before processing. Thanks for the input

Comment: How should a pattern like `(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)` assign the matching groups for `aaaaaaa` other than `(aaaa)(a)(a)(a)`? Also, maybe you want to delete your question.

Comment: @U.Windl, sorry but I don't understand your question

Comment: I meant to say that the original pattern given in the question does not make any sense, but I wanted the OP to think about it (and thus understand).

Answer (score 0):

You miss a / at the end:

```
rename -n 's/(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)(\.SAC)/$4$5$6$1$2/' CA.UTG2..HHZ.D.2015.080.225956.SAC
#                                                          ^
```

And you need your regex like:

```
(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).......
```

Comment: I was missing the `/`at the end, thanks. Is `\d` only for digits? I'm getting no output.

Comment: yes, `\d` is only digits